# how to get a reference to a variable in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a bit of an unusual situation with a tool that I'm not that familiar with. I have a factory called favorite_location and I need two variables from it, the global_id and now the id (as the location_id below). I'm not trying to do anything fancy - just really need this value:

```
  factory :favorite_location, class: GlobalList do
    global_id { FactoryGirl.create(:location).global_id } # would work
    list_id { FactoryGirl.create(:user).liked_restaurant_list.id }
    location_id { FactoryGirl.create(:location).id  } #will fail with duplicate location
  end
```

Is there any way to do the following? I should mention that this is a denormalized relationship.

```
  factory :favorite_location, class: GlobalList do
    { location = FactoryGirl.create(:location) }
    global_id { location.global_id } 
    list_id { FactoryGirl.create(:user).liked_restaurant_list.id }
    location_id { location.id  } #will fail with duplicate location
  end
```

thx for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want to use a transient attribute, to ensure you get a new location with each different favorite_location instance - see https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes

Something like

```
factory :favorite_location, class: GlobalList do
  ignore do
    location_for_vars { create(:location) }
  end

  global_id { location_for_vars.global_id }
  list_id { FactoryGirl.create(:user).liked_restaurant_list.id }
  location_id { location_for_vars.id }
end
```

Comment: thx Peter, this looks to work. kinda funky syntax but appears to allow for local vars.